# In ConcurrentDictionary, is the read operation reading the latest updated value?

Tags: c#, concurrentdictionary

I am using a `ConcurrentDictionary` (`ongoingConnectionDic`) in my code:

1. I check if a serial port number exists in the Dictionary.
2. If not existing, I add it into dictionary.
3. I perform communication with the serial port.
4. I remove the element from the `ongoingConnectionDic`.
5. If existing, I put the thread in wait.

My question is, can I ensure that when I perform a read operation, no other thread is simultaneously writing / updating the value ? So, am I reading the most recent value of the dictionary ?

If not, how do I achieve what I want?

Sample program:

```
    class Program
{
    // Dictionary in question
    private static ConcurrentDictionary<string, string> ongoingPrinterJobs = 
        new ConcurrentDictionary<string, string>();

    private static void sendPrint(string printerName)
    {
        if (ongoingPrinterJobs.ContainsKey(printerName))
        {
            // Add to pending list and run a thread to finish pending jobs by calling print();


        }
        else
        {
            ongoingPrinterJobs.TryAdd(printerName, ""); // -- Add it to the dictionary so that no other thread can
                                                        // use the printer

            ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem(new WaitCallback(print), printerName);
        }

    }

    private static void print(object stateInfo)
    {
        string printerName = (stateInfo as string);
        string dummy;
        // do printing work

        // Remove from dictionary
        ongoingPrinterJobs.TryRemove(printerName, out dummy);
    }


    static void Main(string[] args)
    {

        // Run threads here in random to print something on different printers
        // Sample run with 10 printers
        Random r = new Random();
        for ( int i = 0 ; i < 10 ; i++ )
        {
            sendPrint(r.Next(0, 10).ToString());
        }



    }
```

Comment: Then you need to use a course `lock` on every method of your own implementation of `IDictionary<K, V>`.

Comment: Even doing that though you've just pushing your problem outside of the dictionary. You just can't know that another thread is waiting behind a lock to update the value. So, a latest value may have already computed, but not updated in the dictionary.

Comment: Could you please post your code rather than the vague five steps you've posted in the question?

Comment: I have added the code above. Please suggest. Thanks.

Comment: You get whatever was written last.  If a thread updates the dictionary entry a nanosecond later then what you've read is no longer the last.  A ConcurrentDictionary is thread-safe, that does not automatically how you use it thread-safe as well.

Comment: You really need to post all of your code - you need a [mcve] - because right now I see part of what you're doing and it looks quite fragile. I would **like** to be able to copy and paste your code into a console app or LINQPad and hit run and it would at least compile. Is that possible?

Comment: As Hans says, all that `ConcurrentDictionary` promises is that you can use it concurrently without corrupting the object. That _doesn't_ necessarily mean your use of it will be thread-safe. And in fact, in the little bit of code you posted here, it doesn't look safe: assuming multiple threads, then if one has just checked `ContainsKey()`, it could be preempted and then a different thread could do the same check, then write to the dictionary. Now the first thread _thinks_ the key doesn't exist, and will do the wrong thing.

Comment: The bigger problem with the question though is that, while it's clear the code as posted is not safe, it's not really clear what you're actually trying to accomplish. A good answer will help you solve your _problem_, not just tell you that you haven't done so. But without a better question, there's no way to do that. Please provide a good [mcve] that shows clearly what you're doing, along with a detailed explanation of what the code's supposed to do and, if different, what it does now.

Comment: I have just added a testable / runnable example. Thanks for all the comments / suggestions.

Comment: Any suggestions after I have provided the testable example ?

Answer (score 1):

The concurrent collections take a "snapshot" of the collection upon enumeration. This is to prevent the enumerator from becoming invalid if another thread comes along and writes to the collection.

A method such as `ContainsKey` may enumerate over the items in the dictionary (you'd have to look at the implementation), in which case, you may be reading stale data.

All concurrent collections allow you to do is ensure you can enumerate over a collection even if another thread writes to it while you're enumerating. This wasn't the case with the standard collections.

With that said, as others have mentioned in their comments, other issues of thread safety must still be considered (E.g. race conditions).

The only way to prevent someone inserting a value into the collection after you've attempted to read a value but before writing ia value is to `lock` the collection prior to reading the value to begin with, to ensure synchronized access to the collection throughout the entire transaction (I.e. The reading and subsequent writing of a value).